# Why does gcc generate ARM assembly which put global data's address in a label and repeat in every function

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I wrote this in `C`

```c
int a;
int b[2] = {1, 2};

int main() { return a + b[1]; }
int func() { return a + b[0]; }
```

I used `gcc -S` and `gcc -S -O1` to compiler it and output two assembly files named `asm.s` and `asm-O1.s`

There are two function in this code. Both of them use global variables `a` and `b`

here is the assembly code of `asm.s`

**function func**

```
func:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    str fp, [sp, #-4]!
    add fp, sp, #0
    ldr r3, .L7
    ldr r2, [r3]
    ldr r3, .L7+4
    ldr r3, [r3]
    add r3, r2, r3
    mov r0, r3
    add sp, fp, #0
    @ sp needed
    ldr fp, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
.L8:
    .align  2
.L7:
    .word   b
    .word   a
    .size   func, .-func
    .ident  "GCC: (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

**function main**

```
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    str fp, [sp, #-4]!
    add fp, sp, #0
    ldr r3, .L3
    ldr r2, [r3, #4]
    ldr r3, .L3+4
    ldr r3, [r3]
    add r3, r2, r3
    mov r0, r3
    add sp, fp, #0
    @ sp needed
    ldr fp, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
.L4:
    .align  2
.L3:
    .word   b
    .word   a
    .size   main, .-main
    .align  2
    .global func
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu vfp
    .type   func, %function
```

from the code we can see that function `func` puts the addr of `a` and `b` in the `.L7` section
and the function `main` puts the addr of `a` and `b` in the `.L3` section

why ? for cache ?

and i have another question

here is the code of `asm-O1.s`

```
    .arch armv6
    .eabi_attribute 28, 1
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 2
    .eabi_attribute 30, 1
    .eabi_attribute 34, 1
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "global.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .arch armv6
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu vfp
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    ldr r3, .L2
    ldr r0, [r3, #4]
    ldr r3, .L2+4
    ldr r3, [r3]
    add r0, r0, r3
    bx  lr
.L3:
    .align  2
.L2:
    .word   .LANCHOR0
    .word   a
    .size   main, .-main
    .align  2
    .global func
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu vfp
    .type   func, %function
func:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    ldr r3, .L5
    ldr r0, [r3]
    ldr r3, .L5+4
    ldr r3, [r3]
    add r0, r0, r3
    bx  lr
.L6:
    .align  2
.L5:
    .word   .LANCHOR0
    .word   a
    .size   func, .-func
    .global b
    .comm   a,4,4
    .data
    .align  2
    .set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0
    .type   b, %object
    .size   b, 8
b:
    .word   1
    .word   2
    .ident  "GCC: (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

in the section of function main

I can only see global variable `a`  in `.L2`, why has `b`  disappeared

Comment: Compilers do PC-relative loads of 32-bit addresses from nearby literal pools because (without `movw/movk`) ARM would take even more than 2 instructions to generate a full 32-bit address in a register.  [What does an equals sign = on the right side of a LDR instruction in ARM mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840754).  I haven't looked at your code in detail to see what GCC is doing and whether it's optimizing one literal pool between functions, or if Godbolt is just filtering things out.

Comment: *why b disappeared* - it did not disappear, you just need to scroll further down, see (and use!) https://godbolt.org/z/xxj6Rs. Also, analysing UNoptimized output of gcc is generally a waste of time. Your *why ? for cache ?* question to the first part does not make sense - optimisation is OFF, so the compiler just produces something that works and that's it.

Comment: @tum_: There is no `.word b` in that output, so in that respect it disappeared.  There is a `.set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0` before `b` is defined, so `.LANCHOR0` and `b` have the same address.  Interestingly, if `b[]` is larger, we once again see a `.word b`. https://godbolt.org/z/cjrKG6.  But yeah, this is all compiler internals / minutiae; it seems GCC is using separate literal pools for both functions, unfortunately.

Comment: @Peter Cordes what is `.LANCHOR0,. + 0` mean . been google for a long time , i did't see some doc about it

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55433736/6012693), I provided a link in one of the comments there.

Comment: Terminology note: `.L2, .L3`, etc, are *labels*, not *sections*.  They just mark particular locations in the code (typically so they can be used as branch targets); they aren't meant to break up the code into blocks, nor to describe how it should be laid out in memory (which is what sections do).